# How to use awk and printf to number text from 0 instead of 1?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, printf

Here is the my code that prints out my text in a numbered format:

```
awk '{printf("%s \"%d\" \n" ,$0 , NR)}' mapcycle_surf1.txt
```

Output:

```
"surf_004_final1" "1"  
"surf_1day" "2"  
"surf_2012_beta12" "3"  
"surf_3" "4"
```

How do I start the numbered count from 0 instead of 1 like this:

```
"surf_004_final1" "0"  
"surf_1day" "1"  
"surf_2012_beta12" "2"  
"surf_3" "3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NR-1` is the solution

```
   awk '{printf("%s \"%d\" \n" ,$0 , NR-1)}' mapcycle_surf1.txt
```

Thanks to Tom Fenech for the answer.

Here is the better answer thanks to fedorqui

```
awk '{print $0, NR-1}' mapcycle_surf1.txt
```

Comment: why don't you just say `print $0, NR-1`? No need to use `printf` here.

Comment: @fedorqui I guess the `printf` is useful because is makes adding the `"` characters to the output slightly easier.

Comment: @TomFenech oh, you are right! I hadn't noticed this.

Answer (score 2):

you can just do `print i++`, see below test:

```
kent$ seq 7|awk '{print i++}' 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

with your statement, you can try:

```
awk '{printf("%s \"%d\" \n" ,$0 , i++)}' input
```

Comment: how this answers the question?

Comment: @mathk if you understood the question and my answer, you know how.

Comment: @fedorqui thx, I guess mathk was expecting to see something like `awk '{printf("%s \"%d\" \n" ,$0 , i++)}' `

Comment: You don't seems to make things clear. Either state clearly that you can do arithmetic operation on number which NR is. You are making a state-full awk expression will the OP expression is completely state-less. Ok NR is kind of a state.